# Posting an array of objects to MongoDB with Node sends empty array

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to POST an array of objects to my MongoDB database using NodeJS. When I post, all my fields show up empty. I put my code below, and below that explain what each of the `console.log`s output. Any ideas how to sort this out?

MODEL

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var TransferSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uploadDate: Date,
    period: Number,
    transferCode: String,
    voucherNumber: String,
    vendor: String,
    description: String,
    amount: Number
        });

//convert schema to model
var Transfer = mongoose.model('Transfer', TransferSchema); 

//export model for use elsewhere in app
module.exports = Transfer;
```

AJAX
 - here I've tried posting both `newArray` and `json`. Both result in the same data posted to my db, but have a different effect on the `console.log`s in the controller file.

```
console.log(newArray);
json = JSON.stringify(newArray);
console.log(json);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/transfers/api",
    type: "POST",
    data: newArray,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('posted!');
     },
     error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('failed');
     }
})
```

transferController.js
-when posting `newArray` I get the following: 
`body: [object Object]`, 
`Body: {"undefined": ["", "", "", etc]`, 
`Text: undefined`, 
`Done: undefined`

-when posting `json` I get the following: 
`body: [object Object]`, 
`Body: {"{\"period\":5,\"uploadDate\":2015-11-19T21:00:00.000Z\",\"transferCode\":\"1041\",\"vendor\":\"Lakes State\",\"voucherNumber\":\"0000047571\",\"description\":\"1003-1555 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep               \",\"amount\":456802}...`, 
`Text: undefined`, 
`Done: undefined`

```
//Create a new transfer
function createTransfer(request, response) {
    console.log('posting');
    console.log('body: ' + request.body);                       //TEST
  console.info("Body: " + JSON.stringify(request.body));        //TEST
  console.info("Text: " + JSON.stringify(request.body.text));   //TEST
  console.info("Done: " + JSON.stringify(request.body.done));   //TEST 

    var transfer = new Transfer(request.body);
  transfer.save(function(error) {
    // console.log('transfer and transfer: ' + transfer);

        if(error) return response.json({ message: 'could not create transfer because ' + error });
    response.json({ transfer: transfer });
  });
}
```

EDIT:

I tried using Insomnia to test what I'm sending. Weirdly, the below screenshot posts on Insomnia, but does not post in my app:
[image]

Also interesting, if I post several objects in an array using Insomnia, it does not work, as seen below:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `contentType: 'application/json'` in your ajax request and *stringify* your data like so `JSON.stringify(newArray)`. This should ensure the data you are sending up is ok.

It looks like you are sending up many transfers but then trying to create one transfer from all the data (`request.body`)? You would need to loop over them and create them individually. Something like this:

```
request.body.forEach(function(obj) {
  var transfer = new Transfer(obj);
  transfer.save();
});
```